# How to optimize SQL query with two where clauses?

Tags: mysql

My query is something like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
JOIN tbl2 ON something = something
WHERE 1 AND (tbl2.date = '$date' OR ('$date' BETWEEN tbl1.planA AND tbl1.planB ))
```

When I run this query, it is considerably slower than for example this query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
JOIN tbl2 ON something = something
WHERE 1 AND ('$date' BETWEEN tbl1.planA AND tbl1.planB )
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
JOIN tbl2 ON something = something
WHERE 1 AND tbl2.date = '$date'
```

In localhost, the first query takes about 0.7 second, the second query about 0.012 second and the third one 0.008 second.

My question is how do you optimize this? If currently I have 1000 rows in my tables and it takes 0.7 second to display the first query, it will take 7 seconds if I have 10.000 rows right? That's a massive slow down compared to second query (0.12 second) and third (0.08).

I've tried adding indexes, but the result is no different.

Thanks

Edit : This application will only work locally, so no need to worry about the speed over the web.

Sorry, I didn't include the EXPLAIN because my real query are much more complicated (about 5 joins). But the joins (I think) don't really matter, cos I've tried omitting them and still get approximately the same result as above.

The date belongs to tbl1, planA and planB belongs to tbl2. I've tried adding indexes to tbl1.date, tbl2.planA and tbl2.planB but the result is insignificant.

By schema do you mean MyISAM or InnoDB? It's MyISAM.

Okay, I'll just post my query straight away. Hopefully it's not that confusing.

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_joborder jo
LEFT JOIN tb_project p ON jo.project_id = p.project_id
LEFT JOIN tb_customer c ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
LEFT JOIN tb_dispatch d ON jo.joborder_id = d.joborder_id
LEFT JOIN tb_joborderitem ji ON jo.joborder_id = ji.joborder_id
LEFT JOIN tb_mix m ON ji.mix_id = m.mix_id
WHERE dispatch_date = '2011-01-11'
OR '2011-01-11'
BETWEEN planA
AND planB
GROUP BY jo.joborder_id
ORDER BY customer_name ASC
```

And the describe output

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  jo  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    453     Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  p   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   db_dexada.jo.project_id     1    
1   SIMPLE  c   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   db_dexada.p.customer_id     1    
1   SIMPLE  d   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2048    Using where
1   SIMPLE  ji  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    455      
1   SIMPLE  m   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   db_dexada.ji.mix_id     1
```

Comment: What indexes do you have? What's the output of `DESCRIBE SELECT (your queries)`?

Comment: Also, what's the schema for these tables?

Comment: We really need to know what indexes are used. If you've removed joins and still get the same performance, show the EXPLAIN output for that simplified query. And what exactly have you tried indexing?

Comment: As for schema, I mean what exactly is in your tables there.

Comment: Okay, you've posted EXPLAIN output for the equality-only case, but what's really interesting is the case where we're doing both equality and range search, which is nowhere to be found :) Also, are all of those JOINs relevant? I can't tell, because I still don't know which table had the BETWEEN test...

Comment: oh, my mistake. copied the wrong query :) i've updated it. only 2 tables are relevant, which is tb_dispatch (where dispatch_date resides) and tb_joborder (where planA and planB are). The others are only to get the values of each table (for example to get customer_name, address, etc). I've tried omitting unrelevant tables but the result is insignificant. I think the problem is in the equality and range search.

Comment: Would it be possible to also get the results for the between-only case? I'm wondering what index it was using in that case (the equality-only case is trivial, of course)

Comment: i've tried it, and the explain output is exactly similar as the above. i've removed all the indexes i've put since i don't see any significant difference, but for your information, i indexed dispatch_date, planA and planB.

Comment: Hmm... weird. I can't see why it would have such vastly different performance with the same EXPLAIN output... I guess try UNION as others have suggested, or wait for someone more of an expert than I in mysql query planning to figure out the root cause :/

Comment: if i use UNION suggestion, how can i group the result? because when i tried it, the result is duplicate. For example, queryA UNION queryB. So do I do queryA UNION queryB GROUP BY id or queryA GROUP BY id UNION queryB GROUP BY id?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use UNION to merge results of 2nd and 3d queries.

[More](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) about UNION.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind is to union the two:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1
JOIN tbl2 ON something = something
WHERE 1 AND ('$date' BETWEEN planA AND planB )

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM tbl1
JOIN tbl2 ON something = something
WHERE 1 AND date = '$date'
```

You have provided too little to make optimizations. We don't know anything about your data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Even if most slow queries are usually due to the query itself or index setup of the used tables, you can try to find out where your bottleneck is with using the MySQL Query Profiler, too. It has been implemented into MySQL since Version 5.0.37.

Before you start your query, activate the profiler with this statement:

```
 mysql> set profiling=1;
```

Now execute your long query.

With

```
mysql> show profiles;
```

you can now find out what internal number (query number) your long query has.

If you now execute the following query, you'll get alot of details about what took how long:

```
mysql> show profile for query (insert query number here);
(example output)
+--------------------+------------+
| Status             | Duration   |
+--------------------+------------+
| (initialization)   | 0.00005000 |
| Opening tables     | 0.00006000 |
| System lock        | 0.00000500 |
| Table lock         | 0.00001200 |
| init               | 0.00002500 |
| optimizing         | 0.00001000 |
| statistics         | 0.00009200 |
| preparing          | 0.00003700 |
| executing          | 0.00000400 |
| Sending data       | 0.00066600 |
| end                | 0.00000700 |
| query end          | 0.00000400 |
| freeing items      | 0.00001800 |
| closing tables     | 0.00000400 |
| logging slow query | 0.00000500 |
+--------------------+------------+
```

This is a more general, administrative approach, but can help narrow down or even find out the cause for slow queries very nice.

A good tutorial on how to use the MySQL Query Profiler can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html) in the MySQL articles.

Comment: i've done what you suggested and the part "Copying to tmp table is the main bottleneck here. How do I optimize this?

Comment: This is a result to your Group-By-Clause in the Query and using different tables. If some of columns from a GROUP BY clause are not indexed or if the columns in the GROUP BY clause are from different tables, MySQL will do this. So if the Indexes on the columns are set, then I'd use the UNION-solution the other people in here suggested.